# Solve equation with python

Tags: python, sympy, equation

I hope someone can help me, I try to solve an equation, in principle the idea is to insolate the variable t from the following equation:

```
import math
import sympy
from sympy.solvers import solve
from sympy import Symbol

a=Symbol ('a')

t=Symbol ('t')

S=Symbol('S')

g=Symbol ('g')

h=Symbol('h')          

f=solve(sympy.exp(t*S/2)*(1+(3/2)*t*g*(h-S/2))**(2/(3*g)),t)

print (f)
```

and I get the following:

```
[0.333333333333333*(4.0 - 0**g)/(g*(S - 2.0*h))]
```

When doing it in mathematics wolfram I get a different result, than I get in python, can someone help me to develop this code better? to get the correct result?

[image]

Comment: Can Wolfram compare these two expressions for equivalence?

Comment: Are the sympy and mathematica equations actually the same? They don't look like it.

Comment: There is no mention of `b` in your python code. Also it seems you substituted some value for x (right after gamma in your wolfram code). On top of that, `solve` in sympy sets the equation equal to 0 and finds solutions to that (whereas Wolfram lets you set it equal to anything). You should be subtracting `b` in the equation in your python code so that you can find `t` when the entire expression is equal to 0. Then, write out the python version by hand and compare with what shows up in mathematica

Comment: In the Python example you have an extra "(h-S/2)" in the second factor.  I don't know if that matters but clearly it's different.

Comment: @Milan When suggesting edits please don’t add unnecessary, distracting formatting and text. Marking all text bold is unacceptable.

Answer (score 2):

Your sympy version didn't include the `== b`. In sympy you can add `b` like `solve(expr - b, t)` or `solve(Eq(expr, b), t)`.
Apart from that, your sympy version has `(h - S / 2)` where your Mathematica version has `(X)`. I suppose gamma is just a variable and not the gamma function.

In the code example I changed `S` to lowercase to be able to use sympy's `S` to convert constants involved in divisions symbolically.

Substituting that, the result looks more like Mathematica's.

```py
from sympy import Symbol, solve, exp, S

a = Symbol('a')
b = Symbol('b')
t = Symbol('t')
s = Symbol('s')
g = Symbol('g')
h = Symbol('h')

f = solve(Eq(b, exp(t * s / 2) * (1 + (S(3) / 2) * t * g * (h - s / 2)) ** (S(2) / (3 * g))), t)
```

result (sympy proposes 6 of them):

```
[4*(-s + (2*h - s)*LambertW(-s*exp(3*(2*g*h*log(2**(4/g)*b**3) - g*s*log(2**(4/g)*b**3) + 2*s)/(2*h - s))**(1/6)/(4*(2*h - s))))/(3*g*s*(2*h - s)), 
 4*(-s + (2*h - s)*LambertW(s*exp(3*(2*g*h*log(2**(4/g)*b**3) - g*s*log(2**(4/g)*b**3) + 2*s)/(2*h - s))**(1/6)/(4*(2*h - s))))/(3*g*s*(2*h - s)), 
 4*(-s + (2*h - s)*LambertW(-s*(1 - sqrt(3)*I)*exp(3*(2*g*h*log(2**(4/g)*b**3) - g*s*log(2**(4/g)*b**3) + 2*s)/(2*h - s))**(1/6)/(8*(2*h - s))))/(3*g*s*(2*h - s)),
 4*(-s + (2*h - s)*LambertW(s*(1 - sqrt(3)*I)*exp(3*(2*g*h*log(2**(4/g)*b**3) - g*s*log(2**(4/g)*b**3) + 2*s)/(2*h - s))**(1/6)/(8*(2*h - s))))/(3*g*s*(2*h - s)), 
 4*(-s + (2*h - s)*LambertW(-s*(1 + sqrt(3)*I)*exp(3*(2*g*h*log(2**(4/g)*b**3) - g*s*log(2**(4/g)*b**3) + 2*s)/(2*h - s))**(1/6)/(8*(2*h - s))))/(3*g*s*(2*h - s)), 
 4*(-s + (2*h - s)*LambertW(s*(1 + sqrt(3)*I)*exp(3*(2*g*h*log(2**(4/g)*b**3) - g*s*log(2**(4/g)*b**3) + 2*s)/(2*h - s))**(1/6)/(8*(2*h - s))))/(3*g*s*(2*h - s))]
```

Comment: Was this answer helpful?